# Does the graph of $y + |y| = x + |x|$ represent a function of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is whether or not the graph $y + |y| = x + |x|$ represents a function of $x$. Explain why.

It looks like a weird graph but it would probably be a function because if you say $f(x) = y$ (you get a $y$ value)?

Comment: Doesn't this "graph" fill the entire third quadrant?  That fails the vertical line test pretty dramatically.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that we can plug in any values $x\le 0$, $y\le 0$ and receive an equality.  This shows that for infinitely many values of $x$, there are infinitely many corresponding values of $y$.

In other words, the graph of this equation includes the entire third quadrant of the plane, so it is not a function.  It does not pass the vertical line test.

Now, if we restrict ourselves to positive $x$, then you will find this indeed represents the function $y=x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the pairs:  $(-1,-1),(-1,-2)$

Answer (score 1):

It is a function only if for every $x$ you only have one $y$ value satisfying the equation.

Now look for example the value $x=-1$ and $y=-1$ or $x=-1$ and $y=0$.